# Cannot record audio with PyAudio on Apple Silicon + Big Sur

Tags: python-3.x, pyaudio, macos-big-sur, apple-silicon

**PyAudio** is working fine on my Mac except for **recording**, the frames are always 0, no error.
My mic works with **authorized** apps (GarageBand, etc).
Is it **necessary** and is there a way to **authorize the mic for Python** ?
Thanks.

```
   Python 3.7.9
   Mac mini M1
   OS: Big Sur 11.3
```

Comment: Please mention code so it will be better to understand